# Creating a SQL-Server function which turns negative numbers into null

Tags: sql, sql-server, function

In SQL-Server am trying to create a function which turns negative values (int) into nulls/zero's.
However the ways it is now all the numbers (also the positive ones) get turned into zero.

```
create FUNCTION planning.FN_test_return_zero_incaseof_negative_value (@value as int)

RETURNS int

BEGIN
    if @value < 0 return 0
    DECLARE @days as int


RETURN @days
END
GO
```

Comment: Please tag the RDBMS you’re using. Answers can vary materially between each.

Comment: Why would you have @days in that function?

Comment: You are returning @days - the variable that was declared one step before returning it? What else do you expect to get back from that function? In SQL SERVER: When a variable is first declared, its value is set to NULL.

Comment: My advice would be: don't. Prior to SQL Server 2019 there are well-known issues with performance of scalar-valued functions, as they inhibit parallelism and force row by row processing in many operations. From 2019 onwards things are a little better with function inlining -- when it works -- but even then you are far better off not stuffing trivial expressions like these in a function but just using a `CASE`/`IIF` where needed (as a bonus, that will work on any numeric type, not just `int`). Don't treat T-SQL as a programming language, it barely qualifies.

Comment: Thanks this would be for a database with user input, would it be better to create a trigger with case statements?

Comment: No need for a trigger either. You could have a calculated column that returns the value while keeping the actual entry.

Comment: For simple entry validation, use `CHECK` constraints -- a negative value should probably not be silently converted to 0. If you do want "interesting" logic like that, consider either doing this client-side, or putting the logic in a view (for retrieval) or a stored procedure (for inserting/updating). A trigger is an option, but they have their own problems (limited visibility, more difficult to get right).

Comment: _into nulls/zero's._ Well pick one. You can't do both.

Comment: What do you want to achieve actually? It is very easy to select a null or zero instead of a negative value: `select case when col < 0 then 0 else col end from ...`. But is this what you want? Do you want to do this in a single query? Or do you want to prevent the column from getting negative values via inserts/updates? Or what else?

Comment: Why make a function for this, calling functions in the select clause is never good for performance, you can do this easy with a case or with iif

Comment: *"Thanks this would be for a database with user input,"* Sounds like you should have validation on the application layer to *not* allow negative values, or that it *warns* users that negative values would be changed to `0` on submission (and give them the option to cancel), and have a `CHECK` `CONSTRAINT` on the column that doesn't allow values `< 0`. Then you can't have values `< 0` in the column, and users won't be able to try to do so in the application. A `FUNCTION` in a `TRIGGER` would be a very obscure way to achieve this, and would likely cause confusion for users and developers.

Comment: The moment a user enters a value which results in a negative value in the view this should immediately be corrected. So I thought of putting the function into the query which creates the view, or alternatively a trigger/check constraint. But indeed the more transparant option is a front end 'warning'

Comment: Honestly, this smells like an [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info) after reading the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create FUNCTION planning.FN_test_return_zero_incaseof_negative_value (@value as int)

RETURNS int

BEGIN
    if @value < 0 
       return 0
    return @value
END
GO
```